# How to draw a line on a map between 2 GPS points

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I want to draw a line from one gps point to another. 
Is there a way which uses the streets on the map? And not just the air line?
Does anyone have an example code for android programming in eclipse?
I didn't find any suitable way in google which I will understand. I'm just a beginner. 
Thank you for the outset. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check this blog post I wrote on this topic exactly:

[Google Maps V2: Draw Driving Direction on Map:](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

There is also a sample project there that you can use.

Comment: Thank you for your turorial. I started getting the API key and followed your instructions. But I couldn't display the map. I had the same problem like one guy telling you on your page but I coundn't find an answer "I am trying to get android-support-v4.jar and google-play-services.jar in android dependencies but not able to get. it is always asking me to install support library rev 18. i did it but getting some warning “Warning: Ignoring sample ‘downloaded’: does not contain source.properties.”" I am using Android 4.2.2. - please help me to fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

yes there is its called [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/)